# ExtJs 5 Show data in grid from two stores

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

Is it possible to show data in table from two stores (merge them) without creating third store?
Example:

```
var store1 = {
    data: [{
        name: 'Joe'
    }, {
        name: 'Jane'
    }, {
        name: 'Kate'
    }]
};
var store2 = {
    data: [{
        name: 'John'
    }, {
        name: 'Richard Roe'
    }]
};

var grid = {
    store: [store1, store2]
}
```

Comment: Nope, there isn't. Every grid contains one view, every view is bound to one store.

Answer (score 0):

If both stores' models are same, why don't you merge stores' data ? then load merged data into store1. Like that: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/tjh

```
var mergedData = Ext.Array.union(store1.getRange(),(store2.getRange());
store1.loadData(mergedData);
grid.setStore(store1);

// to provide unique
     store1.on('datachanged', function(store) {
        var checkArray = [];
        Ext.each(store.getRange(), function(record) {
            var userName = record.get('name');
            if (checkArray.indexOf(userName) > -1) {
                store.remove(record);
            }
            checkArray.push(userName);
        });    
    });
```

Comment: This is perfectly possible with ExtJs. It is unnecessary to use a third party library for something plain simple as a union. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Array-method-union

Comment: Thank you for informing me. I wasn't aware Ext has this function. Fixed the my answer.

Comment: In your example you are checking if items are existing (`checkArray.indexOf(userName) > -1`), but that's not necessary if you use `Ext.Array.include`: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Array

Comment: Thank you for keeping me informed, but I am not sure it's more useful than my method?. If possible, could you give an example for this case? Besides, I checked the source codes of that function. It uses ext.array.contains and that also uses 'indexOf'. Btw, I tried this:             Ext.each(store.getRange(), function(record) {
                Ext.Array.include(checkArray, record);
            });    
            store.loadData(checkArray);   . but It gives me an error.

Comment: Nevermind, I just realized I have to get data from record. I wasn't supposed to pushing record.